# CRM 2015 Powershell Get-Organizations fails with Xrm Sdk not found

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm

I'm following the steps enumerated in the Microsoft Technet library to connect to CRM using Powershell - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn689040(v=crm.7).

I was successful in completing "Register the cmdlets" section, but I could not complete #2 of "Use the cmdlet to retrieve organizations from CRM" section.

the error is:

```
    Get-CrmOrganizations : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:12
+ $CRMOrgs = Get-CrmOrganizations –ServerUrl http://myserver:5555
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-CrmOrganizations], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnector.Powershell.Commands.G
   etOrganizations
```

the computer I'm executing this on did not have anything else installed other than the database server itself (in other words executing this on the db server)

has anyone encountered this issue? if so, do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: What is the exact code you are executing?

Comment: you've posted the link to CRM 2015, yet your error clearily indicates that you are running SDK for CRM 2013. Make sure you are using correct SDK for your version and you provided correct path to your SDK (for me it looks like you provided path to SDK 2015 and are running cmdlet from version 2013)

Comment: @JacobH - the code is: $CRMOrgs = Get-CrmOrganizations –ServerUrl http://myserver:5555 –Credential $Cred. I had already set $cred with no issues

Comment: @PawelGradecki -- that's what I thought as well, but I made sure the SDK is for 2015. the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll details show a product version of 7.1.0.1085. I see a version of 2.0.0.282 for Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.dll -- i'm not sure if this version was bundled correctly.

Comment: Try downloading and recompiling it perhaps.

Comment: @JacobH -- what are you suggesting that I download and recompile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked that there is an error in the SDK bundle - for version 2015, the `Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnector.Powershell.dll` (version 1.0.0.0) is dependent upon SDK 2013 (version 6.0.0.0):
[image: sdk]
but `Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector` is dependent upon version 7.0.0.0, so version 2015:
[image: sdk2015]
So this is clearily a bug in SDK. Simply download SDK 2013 and copy your `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll` into the bin folder (where your `Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnector.Powershell.dll` resides)

You can also try downloading SDK for CRM 2016 - it usually is working correctly with older CRM versions, so powershell cmdlets should also be working fine with CRM 2015.

Comment: using Crm365 Sdk works! this is indeed the solution. I find it extremely hard to believe that there's no mention of this issue anywhere, which led to days  of head banging.